# Installing Latest version of git in ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu

My Current git version 1.7.9.5...

I need to upgrade to at least git 1.7.10 to have `git clone` command to work properly

I tried `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa` for upgrading but resulted in this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 125, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 80, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (7, "couldn't connect to host")
```

What am I supposed to do to get the latest git installed (to upgrade)?

Comment: [How can I update to a newer version of Git using apt-get?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33617/12779)

Comment: From the errors/traceback it looks like you have network issue, can you do `sudo apt-get update` on your machine or go to http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/ in your browser?

Comment: In sudo apt-get update its "Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:" but I can go to ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu using my browser

Answer (score 382):

The [Ubuntu git maintainers team has a PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Egit-core/+archive/ppa) just for that

```bash
ppa:git-core/ppa
```

Just do:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

### Error: Unable to locate package `add-apt-repository`

If `add-apt-repository` command is not found, install it first with:

```bash
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

### Error: failed to start the `dirmngr`

If you receive the error:

```bash
gpg: failed to start the dirmngr '/usr/bin/dirmngr': No such file or directory
```

then, install `dirmngr` with:

```bash
sudo apt install dirmngr --install-recommends
```

Comment: The question was what to do when the first command fails showing the above error

Comment: In sudo apt-get update its "Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:" but I can go to ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu using my browser. I dont have any clue on what to do with this network error.

Comment: Maybe it's a firewall thing? Most corporate networks do nasty things with the internet.

Comment: In the update line I'm getting a lot of error 404: W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: That might be because raring is not supported anymore. By any means, pleas update to a newer ubuntu version (if not for git, then for the security updates you will get).

Just in case you don't use raring anymore (good!): Then you should update the ppa source to the version you have (it currently points to a raring repository).

Comment: Please note that if `add-apt-repository` fails with "command not found" on your system, you have to run `apt-get install python-software-properties` first on your Ubuntu

Comment: Possibly useful follow up: Update single apt package: http://askubuntu.com/a/44124/250556

Comment: Please, what is PPA?

Answer (score 25):

The question was: "What to do when `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa` command fails".

I had the same issue in a VM behind a proxy. I resolved it with the following two steps:

1. Set up proxy environment variables

   ```
   export http_proxy=http://<user>:<pwd>@<proxy_url>:<port_number>
   export https_proxy=http://<user>:<pwd>@<proxy_url>:<port_number>
   ```
2. Run the `add-apt-repository` command again as sudo with the `-E` option that preserves the user environment:

   ```
   sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
   ```

Comment: export http_proxy and https_proxy worked, but only as root. Running `sudo -E apt-get update' failed: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA'

Answer (score 4):

**Just follow below commands to update latest version of git**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git -y
git --version
```

Answer (score 1):

To install or update Git in the latest version of Ubuntu, simply type following command in terminal and hit enter (return).

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

For checking Git version.

```
git --version
```

Answer (score 1):

**Install Git in Ubuntu**

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install git
3. sudo apt-get install gitk git-gui

Answer (score 0):

or super manual method

download git source from git hub and then

```
make prefix=/usr/local all
sudo make prefix=/usr/local install
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-ubuntu-14-04