# Ignoring GIT Submodule Locally

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project like this:

```
main_module
-folder
--submodule_pub1
--submodule_pub2
--submodule_sec
```

Not everyone reaches the `submodule_sec`. Is there a way for this people to check out the `main_module` and all public submodules, but remove the `submodule_sec` but only locally? With somehow mark it locally unchanged?

I have found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260982/337621
My problem, that I do not want to make a commit, and I do not want to have the removed submodule as untracked change. Is there a way to do this? Which commands do I need for the example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try, [with recent git 1.8.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309), a:

```
git submodule deinit -- folder/submodule_sec
```

From the [`git submodule` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule):

> Further calls to git submodule update, git submodule foreach and git submodule sync will skip any unregistered submodules until they are initialized again,

Since it unregisters a submodule, removing it from the `.git/config file`, that means it is only a local modification of the *local* config: it doesn't affect the submodule itself, which continues to be referenced by the parent repo, both in the working tree and in the `.gitmodules` files.
But the  `git submodule update` command won't initialize and checkout a submodule that you just `deinit`.

Comment: How do I install it on Ubuntu? The latest is 1.8.1 in the package manager. Is there an easy way to install the latest?

Comment: @GáborLipták the answer for installing the latest git on Ubuntu was on Stack Overflow 45 minutes ago ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/19109661/6309