# How to debug git svn fetch invalid XML

Tags: git, svn

I try to convert a SVN repository to git using `git2svn`. My server uses username and password.

I did

```
svn2git https://example.com/svn/bar
```

And get the error

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/bar/.git/
Error from SVN, (130003): XML data was not well-formed: The REPORT response contains invalid XML (200 OK)

command failed:
git svn fetch
```

When doing `git svn fetch` in the new folder, I get the same error.

How can I debug this? `git svn fetch` does not seem to have a `--verbose` option.

```
svn co https://example.com/svn/bar
```

works...

**edit**

Based on the answer by kan I tried several things:

- I disabled authentication on the repo
- I disabled HTTPS
- I downloaded subgit

Subgit shows

```
error: Import has been interrupted; --svn-url option is not valid at the moment.
```

After calling it with subgit import --svn-url http://example.com/svn/bar bar.git

it works.

I also did a network analysis using wireshark and saw comments with German umlauts. Does maybe svn2git have encoding problems here?

```
auskommentierten Legacy-Code endg\374ltig entfernt
```

and seems not even to do any connection.

Comment: What version of git are you using?

Comment: is this to any help http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_22.html

Comment: @VonC: git version 1.9.1 - okay I guess that is pretty damn old.

Comment: On which OS are you using this command? Any chance to check if it would work with a more recent version of git?

Comment: I just upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04. Git is now at 2.1.4 - problem persists.

Comment: @Mats: This seems to apply to a checked-out svn with a .svn directory. I don't have such. It's being freshly checked out via git-svn

Comment: Just to be sure, I assume the issue persists with git 2.4.8 or 2.5? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19109661/6309)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`svn co` may works well only because it checks out last revision, while `git svn` downloads the whole repository. So, probably the remote repository is corrupted at some revision.

A few things to try:

1. Use a tool to capture http traffic
2. If you have direct access to the repository (not via https), try using it
3. Use svnrdump to download whole dump of the repository into your local drive and try to play with it.
4. Try to use subgit instead.