# How to properly handle a discontinuity in git-svn

Tags: git-svn

I am in a situation where (say) commit 666 is dodgy, i.e

```
git svn clone [REPO] -r665 #works
git svn clone [REPO] -r666 #Malformed XML
git svn clone [REPO] -r667 #works
```

but even weirder

```
git svn clone [REPO] -r665
cd [REPO_NAME]
git svn fetch -r667 #Malformed XML
git svn fetch -r668 #Malformed XML
git svn fetch -r669 #Malformed XML
...
```

(this also happens with analogous commands in SVN)

currently, the only way I know around this is either

- forgo having any history before r666
- using 2 svn repos pointing to the same remote and hacking around with rebase/cherry pick

Is there a more proper way to do this?

Comment: Do you do a one-time conversion or do you want to commit back from the Git clone to the SVN repo?

Comment: I want to be able to fetch from SVN in the future but not commit back to it.

Comment: Hm, I'd ask IT about that. Sounds like a corrupted repository or an intervening anti-virus program on server or client side maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember hacking `git cherry-pick` to fix this

I did something along the lines of (disclaimer: untested):

```
git-svn init -R one -s [SVN-URL]
git-svn init -R two -s [SVN-URL] -r667
git checkout [svn-remote-one-trunk]
git checkout -b git-master
git cherry-pick [first commit SHA of svn-remote-two-trunk]
#Fix conflicts
git cherry-pick [svn-remote-two-trunk]
```

had to do this several times and `git-master` is incompatible with the svn remotes so it would either have to be discarded or any svn work would have to go on the svn branches and I had to incorporate cherry picking into my workflow until everyone got migrated to git.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar error because of [character encoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31728400/6309)

One good test is to try the same import with the free version of [SubGit](https://subgit.com/) (for one time conversion only: a two-way conversion is not free)

That tool (`subgit import --svn-url http://example.com/svn/bar bar.git`) is more robust and could handle "Malformed XML" better.