# Can't change git default branch to main on the command line

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

I've read on several sites that you can use `git config --global init.defaultBranch main` to change the default branch (from master) to main. But it doesn't work for me. Here it's from my terminal (my os is ubuntu):

```
$ git config --list
user.email=*************
user.name=********
credential.helper=store
core.editor=nano

$ git config --global init.defaultBranch main
$ git config --list
user.email=*************
user.name=*************
credential.helper=store
core.editor=nano
init.defaultbranch=main

$ mkdir testrepo
$ cd testrepo
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/Desktop/testrepo/.git/

$ git status
On branch master
No commits yet
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: What git version do you have?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The option `init.defaultBranch` was [introduced in Git version 2.28](https://github.blog/2020-07-27-highlights-from-git-2-28/#introducing-init-defaultbranch). You must be running an older version which does not honor this option.

Comment: Thanks that's it. Strange that apt only updates git to 2.25.1 and not 2.28

Comment: Also nice to point out that you wouldn't know it when adding the config. You can literally add anything: `git config --global abcd.efg blahblah` and it'll accept it and show it in your config list.

Comment: @TunHuang: the apt repositories for various Ubuntu versions try to avoid leading (or sometimes "bleeding") edge versions of various programs. To update Git to newer versions with apt, you must add extra archives ("PPAs"). See [some answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19109542/1256452) (not all of them mention the PPAs).